# is hadoop DistributedFileSystem thread safe?

Tags: java, hadoop, thread-safety, distributed-filesystem

I am using hadoop for writing data I scrape.

I have a spring service that is called from multiple threads to write some content to the HDFS.

```
@Service
public class WriteService
{
    public void write(String path, String content)
    {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether the FileSystem object can be a member of the WriteService and I don't find whether it is thread safe or not.
I am using the DistributedFileSystem object.

Do you know if it is thread-safe and I can use it as a member to my service?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop DFS uses a so-called [WORM-Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many). This makes it more robust when it comes to concurrency issues.

**But**, to answer the question, it is **not** safe in general. You still need to think about concurrency control requirements.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thank you. Currently every time the write method is called I am doing FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration); It seems like a bit of an heavy operation, can you please give me a hint how to do it?

Comment: @user1002065 With respect to the amount of writes you perform, i'd keep your solution. One thing you might should read about is the [try-with-ressource statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: @user1002065 `With respect to the amount of writes`: i wanted to point out, that you shouldn't care about premature optimization :)

Comment: I am going to have many writes, but I care more about data be written concurrently. But I guess I will take your advice and when it is going to extend I will try to find a better solution for optimization. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If  `config.setBoolean("fs.hdfs.impl.disable. cache", true);`  is modified first, `FileSystem.get(config)` can be used in multiple threads.